# CCAvenue Transaction - Integration

Tags: php, jar, payment, ccavenue

I have integrated CcAvenue Payment Gateway into my project for transactions.
There is one issue viz.

```
I am unable to get the status of $AuthDesc after a transaction.
After contacting the customer service they replied saying there is a
problem in my integration code.
The file that they provided has the following code:
```

> > $WorkingKey = "" ; //put in the 32 bit working key in the quotes provided here
> >         $encResponse=$_REQUEST["encResponse"];
> >         exec("java -jar ccavutil.jar $WorkingKey \"$encResponse\" dec",$ccaResponse);
> >         $tok = strtok($ccaResponse[0],"&");

```
However, i am unable to run the jar file and $ccaResponse returns an empty array
always.I know this question belongs to a particular software but i need help 
from programmers who have done this before.
Kindly help.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you don't able to run the jar file is **`your hosting provider doesn't support the execution of the jar file`**. To overcome this issue, you have to **`contact the customer support of CCAvenue`** and **`ask them to provide the integration kit which only contain php files`**.

They have the kit and they will provide it if you call them(if you need it fast) or mail them.The new kit contain the following files

```
 1. adler32.php
 2. Aes.php
 3. Checkout.php
 4. Index.html
 5. redirecturl.php
```

They have the kit like this for all type of programmers.